# Transition from KERDI membrane backed, to not backed

Tags: tile, kerdi

I intend to use [KERDI membrane](https://www.schluter.com/schluter-us/en_US/Membranes/Waterproofing-(KERDI)/Schluter%C2%AE-KERDI/p/KERDI) behind some new bathroom wall tiling backed by drywall.

How feasible is it to transition from using the membrane to not using the membrane on a neighboring section of the same wall (i.e. only one section of the wall needs waterproofing, but the transition shouldn't be noticeable once tiled).

The specs say the membrane is 8mm thick, but I'm not sure if that'll be too large a transition for a good tile finish.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use Denshield for tiling bathroom surrounds. It is the same thickness as the drywall and it comes with a waterproof membrane already installed on it.  This means that there is no transition disparity between the drywall and the DenShield.

You can run the final row of tile over the joint between the Denshield  and of the drywall.  You need to use a fiber mesh tape and a liquid waterproof membrane over the seams and  corners any of the screwheads but the rest of the field is already waterproof and textured to except tile.

You would remove the existing sheet rock where you are going to tile and replace it with the denshield.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why it says 8mm.  It’s definitely not 8mm thick.  It is less than 1mm.  You can compensate for the thickness difference w/ a bit more of thinset.  It is a membrane, not a board.  At 8mm it would be impossible to fit in the corners.

update: i found a scrap piece of kerdi yesterday and a penny is a bit thicker than 3 layers of kerdi

[image: kerdi and a penny]

Answer (score 1):

Look a little closer at the Schluter website. They have a complete system for waterproofing bathrooms. I don't think the Kerdi membrane is that thick. That stuff is awesome second only to Wedi.

Comment: Thanks. The specs I can find say 8mm, but a few folks have said that's incorrect, so I'm going to order some anyhow